# Why Xilinx ISE can't get access to my custom package?

Tags: vhdl, xilinx, ise

I am trying to create a custom data type which I am creating in a package using Xilinx ISE 14.5. I am trying to create a generic DEMUX to switch between buses, here is the code of the generic DEMUX:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;
use work.CustomDataTypes.all;

entity GenericDEMUX is
     -- Ancho del bus de cada salida y número de salidas
     generic( busWidth              : integer := 4;
                 channelsNumber     : integer := 4
     );

    Port (  Output  : out  Matrix(channelsNumber-1 downto 0, busWidth-1 downto 0);
                Control : in     integer range 0 to channelsNumber-1
     );
end GenericDEMUX;

architecture Behavioral of GenericDEMUX is

begin


end Behavioral;
```

So I created a Package to contain `Matrix` data type:

**CustomDataTypes.vhd:**

```
package CustomDataTypes is
    type Matrix is array (natural range<>) of STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (natural range<>);

end CustomDataTypes;
```

When I do `Check Syntax` on the Generic DEMUX I get this errors:

> ERROR:HDLParsers:164 - "//vboxsrv/datos/Datos/Micro
>   UTN/FPGA/MaquinaEstados/CustomDataTypes.vhd" Line 14. parse error,
>   unexpected NOTCONSTRAINT
>
> ERROR:HDLParsers:3009 -
>   "//vboxsrv/datos/Datos/Micro
>   UTN/FPGA/MaquinaEstados/CustomDataTypes.vhd" Line 35. Package
>   CustomDataTypes does not exist.

I don't know what `parse error, unexpected NOTCONSTRAINT` means but I think it could be related to `Package CustomDataTypes does not exist`. Here is a Screenshot of what my Libraries tab looks like, as you can see `CustomDataTypes.vhd` is there:

[image]

However I don't see it in the design tab:

[image]

I tried adding it but it says it already exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately not until VHDL-2008 were unconstrained arrays of unconstrained elements allowed.

In other words, for pre VHDL-2008:

```
type Matrix is array (natural range<>) of std_logic_vector(natural range<>);
```

Would have to become either something like:

```
type Matrix_n_by_8 is array (natural range<>) of std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
```

Or use 2d arrays:

```
type Matrix is array(natural range<>, natural range<>) of std_logic;
```

Comment: Wow that worked. So `type Matrix is array (natural range<>) of std_logic_vector(natural range<>);` is only for VHDL-2008 which Xilinx ISE doesn't support?

Comment: PS: How can I access the array in each index because `Output <= "0000"` gives `Wrong index type for Output`

Comment: @Andres Correct.  I'm not even sure if Vivado supports any VHDL-2008.

Comment: @Andres PS: You access the 2-d array with a comma: m(0,0) <= '0'.  You can define functions that make vector assignment easier.